# WooCommerce how to get the list of my account items?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to get all the menu items under the WooCommerce My account but it returns only the default items.

This function `wc_get_account_menu_items()` returns
`array(6) { ["orders"]=> string(6) "orders" ["downloads"]=> string(9) "downloads" ["edit-address"]=> string(12) "edit-address" ["payment-methods"]=> string(15) "payment-methods" ["edit-account"]=> string(12) "edit-account" ["customer-logout"]=> string(15) "customer-logout" }`

But this does not have subscriptions or an appointment menu.

I believe these were added through `woocommerce_account_menu_items` filter. But how can I have the current list of current menus with links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<pre>wc_get_account_menu_items:-';
print_r( wc_get_account_menu_items());
echo '</pre>';
```

It prints all the menus.

[image]